# IF statement for binning data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers in the 1st column. Based on the number in the 1st column I want to give each line another number i.e. if cell A2 has a value of bigger than 1300 and less than 1400, in B2 I want the cell to show `6.75`.

- If A1 has a value of 1350, then B1 will update with a value of "6.75".
- If A1 has a value of 1450, then B1 will update with a value of "7.25", and so on.

There are 17 groupings that I need:

<1300 >1400 =6.75
<1400 >1500 =7.25
<1500 >1600 =7.75
<1600 >1700 =8.25
.
.
.
Bigger than 2900 =14.75

I could have numerous values on the spreadsheet in the 1st column so need to put them into a grouping bucket using some formula.

Any ideas?

Comment: user2727573, I've updated the bullet points to make more sense in conjunction with your first paragraph. Can you please check that that's what you _meant_ otherwise you'll need to add some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple linear relationship like that, you could use a formula along the lines of:

```
=if(a1<1300, 0, if(a1>=2900, 14.75, (trunc(a1 / 100, 0) - 13) * 0.5 + 6.75))
```

In other words, check the too-low and too-high values first to deliver fixed results, otherwise use the final formula to convert to the desired number.

This involves dividing by 100 to turn (for example) `1727` into `17`, subtracting `13` to get `4`, multiplying that by `0.5` and adding the `6.25` base to get `8.75`.

That will give you what you've asked for:

```
        x < 1300:  0.00
1300 <= x < 1400:  6.75
1400 <= x < 1500:  7.25
1500 <= x < 1600:  7.75
1600 <= x < 1700:  8.25
1700 <= x < 1800:  8.75
1800 <= x < 1900:  9.25
1900 <= x < 2000:  9.75
2000 <= x < 2100: 10.25
2100 <= x < 2200: 10.75
2200 <= x < 2300: 11.25
2300 <= x < 2400: 11.75
2400 <= x < 2500: 12.25
2500 <= x < 2600: 12.75
2600 <= x < 2700: 13.25
2700 <= x < 2800: 13.75
2800 <= x < 2900: 14.25
2900 <= x       : 14.75
```

You can see it in action from the following screen shot, showing the edge cases:
[image]

---

Note that you have a problem with your description of numbers like 1400 since you don't specify which range they should fall in. For the formula given above, the ranges are inclusive at the low end and exclusive at the high end (such as `1300..1399.9999`).

---

If the relationship isn't so linear (or, more accurately, formulaic), you will probably need to consider the use of lookup tables as per the excellent suggestion by `pnuts`.

Comment: @pnuts, I'm putting that down to a confused question, transposition of rows/columns, since the question was not internally consistent. Have requested clarification from OP but the way I've answered seems to be the most likely scenario.

Comment: @retailcoder, a faulty memory chip in my skull :-) Have fixed it now.

Comment: Actually I just tested it - and learned that it's not only valid, it interestingly seems to be converting the result to a `mailto:` hyperlink... didn't know that *lolx* (pun @ question's title)!

Comment: @retailcoder, I can only assume OP is laughing out loud while blowing a kiss to us all, something that seems rather difficult when you think about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like `=VLOOKUP(A3,bArray,2)` should suit, copied to suit, where `bArray` is the name for a two column list of the breakpoints and the values up to the respective breakpoint.

[image: SO18501453 example]

The break points may require slight adjustment to suit whatever is actually required.

Comment: I was just about to ask why 2900 generated 9.75 but you fixed it (presumably the range was misconfigured). In any case, it's fixed now so my question is moot.  For the outside ranges, you could just use if-functions to detect that before trying the lookup, a la `=if(a1<1300,0,if(a1>=2900,14.75,vlookup(...)))`.

Comment: ...Or just add a `0` lookup value to the `bArray`. The `>=2900` condition is already taken care of with the way `vlookup` works, nesting it in `IF` conditions isn't necessary. I would explicitly do `VLOOKUP(__,bArray,2,TRUE)` though.

Comment: Aw, that would *mootinize* my upvotes on your two [very nice] answers!